# Is there a way to collect dynamically created HTML and transform that into PDF using mPDF?

Tags: html, pdf, mpdf

I am working on a website where users can create elements dynamically. They start with an empty list like this:

```
<ul id='list'>

</ul>
```

They can add items and print it when they are done.

I let them print the HTML with a piece of javascript but it would be a lot nicer and friendlier to create a PDF. I want to use mPDF to create a pdf with the created list. I have looked at a few examples but none discuss pdf creation with dynamic content.

Is this possible with mPDF?

Comment: Take a look at the free tfpdf library. Works really great, is capable of unicode and allows document layout as fine grained as you want to.

Comment: @arkascha I will take a look at it, but I don't see how I would achieve this. The documentation on tfpdf is very limited as far as I have seen. Do you maybe have a few good examples on how to collect HTML and transform this in a PDF with good styling options.

Comment: OK, if html styling is the main focus here then tfpdf might not be the best choice. For a documentation you use the fpdf page. It is the same thing, only tfpdf ads utf compatibility amongst other things. Their approach is not to render html, but to allow to construct a documents content. So you would take the html DOM and iterate over the list elements yourself and position their representation on the pdf. As said: great control, much more than "just" printing html, but certainly it's more effort than taking a styled html document and "printing" that.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks. Yes I need to style...and I do want to use PDF creation. Just printing has also cross-browser issues that are hard to resolve. I will see if there is something out there that fits my needs, but I am afraid a free solution is hard to find :)

Comment: For cross browser styling for printing of html you should use the different media options css offers. You can make styling rules specific for printing. But I agree that creating a pdf document delivers a better solution. Though I doubt you will get it with attempting to convert html to pdf. You keep exactly those problems that show themselves in those "cross browser issues", so that html does not allow precise styling, whilst you gain nothing from using a pdf format. Why not create real pdf content? It is not that hard to do...

Comment: Yes I know about media options and cross browser styling. That is all fine. I am using AngularJS, but to write a printing script that works in all browsers in AngularJS without using jQuery plugins is not really easy. By the way, does mPDF not use the same concept as fPdf?

Comment: I have no experience with mPDF. What I saw in the examples gave me the impression that it has a different approach compared to fpdf/tfpdf: mpdf appears to render html, just as you mentioned in your question. But I may be completely wrong there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have played around with fpdf for a while and it is indeed great for pdf making. My problem is that the list items contain nested elements in a non predictable order. It seems pretty hard to achieve this with fpdf. If it was only a listitem with some text fpdf is definetly the way to go here, but I very much doubt if it will get the desired result for me. Thanks for your insights anyway, pdf making from html seems a taboo on this forum :)

Comment: I suggest you use a DOM parser in php to iterate through the structure. That way you can render the elements one by one in the order and nesting level they appear. But indeed there are different approaches.